# Bulk rename a group of files with asterisks (*) in the name to hashs (#)

Tags: bash, special-characters, rename, bulk

I've got a list of files:

```
file*1.ext
fil*e2.ext
fi*le3.ext
```

I want to rename these to:

```
file#1.ext
fil#e2.ext
fi#le3.ext
```

The command:

```
rename -v 's/\*/\#/' *
```

gives me:

```
Unknown option: 0
Unknown option: 0
Unknown option: 0
Unknown option: 1
Unknown option: 1
Unknown option: 1
Unknown option: 2
Unknown option: 2
Unknown option: 2
Unknown option: 3
Unknown option: 4
Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: My `rename` is different than yours.  What package is your `rename` come from?  Is it `/usr/bin/rename`?

Comment: on my system your command executes successfully as-is..

Comment: Yes **Note:** there are 2 **entirely different** `rename` packages that exist out in the computing world. One fairly robust, one minimal. Confirm which version you have before selecting it for use.

Comment: @RobinHsu yes it's found at /usr/bin/rename.
rename --version is not understood

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin how can I check my version?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I have my other distribution having your rename:
This should work:

```
rename 's/\*/#/' *
```

Comment: Another package of rename should work with this: `rename '*' '#' *`

Answer (score 0):

This will work on all system with bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=*.ext
for file in $files; do
file="${file:0:-4}"
[[ "$file" == *"*"* && -f $file.ext && ! -L $file.ext ]] &&
newfile="${file//'*'/'#'}" && mv "$file.ext" "$newfile.ext"
done
```

It will ignore directories and symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that nothing (including backslash) is escaped in sigle quotes. Therefore, you should have not added the backslashes.

```
$ rename --version
rename (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)

$ ls
file*1.ext  fil*e2.ext  fi*le3.ext

$ rename  '*' '#' *

$ ls
file#1.ext  fil#e2.ext  fi#le3.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be done with bash **substring replacement**:

```
for i in *\**; do mv "$i" "${i//\*/#}"; done
```

**Example/Use**

```
$ ls -1 *\**
fi*le3.ext
fil*e2.ext
file*1.ext

$ for i in *\**; do mv "$i" "${i//\*/#}"; done

$ ls -1 *\**
ls: cannot access ***: No such file or directory

$ ls -1 *#*
fi#le3.ext
fil#e2.ext
file#1.ext
```